# Archive mysql 6 months old data to other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, percona

I am running a shopping website and there is a lot of data in order table.

Now I want to archive 6 months old data in a separate table like `order_archive`.

But my problem is that if I am doing so I have to change all my queries where order table is used because this table `order` will not contain old data and I have to write other query for old order.

Please suggest me what are the possible way to go around of this problem.

Comment: I've removed my comments.

Comment: You could use a `UNION` in your `SELECT` statement to `SELECT` from both tables at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Rather archiving data each day and change all your queries to get results from both i would suggest to create partitions, this will keep only one table for your reference and give better performance though all data in in same table.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a view to reference the data.  Something as simple as:

```
CREATE VIEW orders_all AS
    SELECT * FROM orders UNION 
    SELECT * FROM orders_archive
```

The application code can then reference that view instead of the table when fetching data.

Of course, you're going to run into issues if you need to *update* an archived record, since you can't update this view.  But then, if you need to update the data or modify it in any way then it really shouldn't be "archived" in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

you can use trigger for that purpose, Before to use trigger create a backup table then use it. for ex i am creating for insert into table. As told above view can't update. you can set up trigger for update also and your order_archive table contains updated and new data.

```
create table order_archive as select * from order; 
insert into order values (1,2);

mysql> delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER order_like BEFORE INSERT ON order
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO order_archive values(NEW.a1, NEW.a2);
  END;//
mysql> delimiter ;
```